# How to map recursive class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have Employee and Department classes.

Employee class contain Department and Department contain Employee.

I want to map this class from VM.Employee to GM.Employee.

```
class VM.Employee 
{
    int Id {get;set;}   
    int Name {get;set;}   
    VM.Department dept{get;set;}
}

class VM.Department 
{
    int Id {get;set;}   
    int Name {get;set;}  
    VM.Employee {get;set;}
}

class GM.Employee 
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    int Name {get;set;}
    GM.Department dept{get;set;}
}

class GM.Department 
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    int Name {get;set;}
    GM.Employee {get;set;}
}
```

I want to write mapper VM.Employee to GM.Employee.
As it contain recursive class Employee so Automapper is not allowing to do.

Comment: What are `VM` and `GM` and why can't they use the same class?

Comment: Use automapper.http://automapper.org/

Comment: VM and GM are Namespaces.

Comment: Just name the classes uniquely. If they share something common, derive them from base class. Using namespaces in class name is not recommended.

Comment: Why do you have the same object replicated twice in different namespaces?

Comment: As my Class name are same so i have to use Namespaces.

Comment: @HemantMalpote - By the looks of things, the classes are the exact same in each namespace so why can't you just use of these for both purposes?

Comment: It is not possible to use same class. Since i have to map few more class in which source and destination may having few properties different.

Comment: Is there any way to map only those property which are possible and get list of properties which are not possible to map